# Reset Forms Model Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an asp.net core form with many textboxes.  I want to add a cancel button so that a user can restore the form to its original model values.

I need to avoid a postback.

I'm using jquery to hide show the edit save cancel buttons.

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('.save, .cancel').show();
});
$('.cancel').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.edit').show();
    $(this).siblings('.save').hide();
    $(this).hide();
});
$('.save').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.edit').show();
    $(this).siblings('.cancel').hide();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

How can I rig the cancel button to reset the form to the model values:

Something like:

```
$('.save').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.edit').show();
    $(this).siblings('.cancel').hide();
    $(this).hide();
    var $form = this.closest('form'); 
    $form.resetForm();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take your entire server-side model and turn it into a `Javascript` object by doing the following:

```
<script>
    function resetToDefault(){
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        for (var prop in model) {
            var controlId = prop;
            var value = model[prop];
            $('.' + controlid).val(value);
        }
    }
</script>
```

But if you want to clear form try like this:

```
$("#idForm").reset();
```

Comment: Right so I'm guessing then I have to manually reset each textbox in jquery which also means I am no longer using my strongly typed data model?

Comment: @Reafidy so You need set Controls Value manually with `for` or `foeEach`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
$('#reset').click(function () {$('#in1,#in2,#in3'...).val('');});
```

[LINK](https://forums.asp.net/t/2137296.aspx?How%20to%20clear%20all%20user%20entered%20data%20on%20all%20fields%20of%20razor%20view%20) You can see here too;)

Comment: That appears to be clearing the form.  I want to reset each input to the modal value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( '#myForm' ).each(function(){
    this.reset();
});
```